# Answer to 11 year old question

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

Is there any sense of answer (like I did :D ) to 11 year old question? (the OP and another answer user are no longer part of SE)
And is it make any sense bot to show it in the front page of Serverfault?

Answer (score 4):

The ideal is that bad questions get closed.

Good questions don't get closed, not by the community, not automatically nor do they expire over time.  Implied are that good questions are not only relevant for the person who originally posted them and that any answers will also benefit others regardless.

A result of that philosophy is that there is no time limit to when that answer may be posted, even once another answer has already been accepted, it is still possible to post additional answers. Even  ***11 years later*** (as evidenced by you) answers can still be added.

Admittedly the older the question, the more likely that whoever asked the question has moved on and any answers won't be accepted, but a good answer is still valuable on its own.

And that is also exactly what the Community ["*user*"](https://serverfault.com/users/-1/community) intends to encourage by randomly poking old unanswered questions and bumping those to the front page.

Unfortunately not every question ages well and it makes little sense to answer many of those today...

Comment: It is sad this question do not get valuable answer (IMHO) in right time. And I have my doubts about my answer because software companies change (probably) a lot for these 11 years. The odd (and funny) part is OP do not exist anymore. So I can't expect to have my answer accepted :)

Comment: One more point. This procedure with bumping questions may go to infinite loop. OP is no longer part of SE, question is unanswered. Community user bump it, someone post good answer, but because of absence of OP answer can't be accepted. And Community user may bump it again and again...

Answer (score 4):

A question does not need to be accepted to stop it from being pushed to the front page.

Unanswered questions get bumped to the front page. An unanswered question is a question that has no upvoted answers.

To stop unanswered questions of any age from being pushed to the front page, upvote one of the answers (if applicable).

Comment: So there is also other criteria (upvote for example) to make question answered for community user. Thank you for clarification. :)